# Trouble with updating Data trough PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with this code, it does delete a row but not editing one.  I cannot figure out how to make it work.
Here's the script:

```
<?php
if($_POST['delete']){

    $i = 0;
    while(list($key, $val) = each($_POST['checkbox'])) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$val'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        $i += mysql_affected_rows();
    }

    // if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php
    if($i > 0){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=data.php">';
    }
}

if($Submit){
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET naam='$naam[$i]', achternaam='$achternaam[$i]', leeftijd='$leeftijd[$i]', straat='$straat[$i]', postcode='$postcode[$i]', telefoon='$telefoon[$i]', email='$email[$i]', geslacht='$geslacht[$i]', pakket='$pakket[$i]', WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
        $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }
}

mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: You are not describing a specific problem. Please try to go into more detail about what exactly doesn't work

Comment: $Submit is not being set anywhere in that code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out $Submit isn't defined before the `if` statement - also $tbl_name isn't defined either so it would bring back an error if the `if` statement was triggered.

Also in $result1 you used $sql1 - $sql1 has not been defined.

You're vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=What+are+SQL+injections+and+how+can+I+prevent+them%3F) like Pekka said, so I advise reading up on it, always, ALWAYS validate user inputted data, never trust anyone :)

Also, you don't need to print a meta refresh, you can just use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header ("Location: data.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$Submit` is not defined before it is used. So, its value will be `null` which is a `falsy` value. Hence `if` loop will never get executed.

Comment: Maybe this gives more insight : www.iimages.org/data.txt

Comment: i checked the file. $Submit is not defined before it is used

Answer (score 0):

`$Submit` is not defined (as others already mentioned). Also, if you do define `$Submit` then `$count` is still undefined. So you still won't get into the for loop. And if `$count` is defined, your code still does not update the database. You store your sql query in `$sql` but pass `$sql1` , which has not been set, as query that should be executed.

And your code is wide open for sql injection. You [should not](http://xkcd.com/327/) want that.